# R Reactive values - unique added to list

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Reactive values might be a curse to someone from different programming language background;)
The task ahead (simplified for SO) - I want to download new file whenever new country is within the map boundaries. In the example below you would need a shapefile, for example this one: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
UI is as simple as it can be:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap"))
```

The server is not overly complicated (yet;)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)

countries<- readShapeSpatial("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

displayed<-c("United Kingdom")

server <- function(input, output,session) {

 output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(countries) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng=-0.1294984,lat=51.4992921,zoom=10)

})

pointsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$mymap_bounds))
      return(NULL)
    bounds <- input$mymap_bounds
    N<- bounds$north
    S<-bounds$south
    E<-bounds$east
    W<-bounds$west
    BB = matrix(c(W,E,E,W,W,N,N,S,S,N), nrow=5,ncol=2)
    BB = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(BB)),1)))
    as.vector(countries[which(gIntersects(countries,BB,byid=TRUE)),]$NAME)
  })}
```

So the `pointsinbounds()` tells me what countries are visible, `displayed` is a list of what is already downloaded (to avoid re-downloading).
What i want to achieve is to add (and keep) `pointsinbounds()` to `displayed` list and observe the `displayed` list if it changes (to trigger downloads only if a new country is within the boundaries). I managed adding to the list by `unique(c(displayed,pointsinbounds()))` but it does not store it permanently - when I move out of France it removes France from the list. As well it reacts whenever `pointsinbounds()` change, while i want to react only when the total list changes, to avoid recalculation when you move back to the same country.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want you may use one of two options.

1) To store the values into a  reactiveValues().In this case the country list will be persistent during that session.

2) To store the value in a global value, and it will be persistent between sessions, and accessible between sessions/users (you can put the assignment in global.R).

EDIT: In option 2, added code to detect new countries.

Note: In the examples below I added a control to monitor the country list.

Example for option 1

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)


ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap") ,
                verbatimTextOutput('myCountries'))

countries <- readShapeSpatial("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

displayed <- c("United Kingdom")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r <- reactiveValues()


  observe({
    r$displayed <- unique(c(r$displayed, pointsInBounds())) 
  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(countries) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -0.1294984,
              lat = 51.4992921,
              zoom = 10)
  })

  output$myCountries <- renderPrint({
    r$displayed 
  })


  pointsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$mymap_bounds)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    bounds <- input$mymap_bounds
    N <- bounds$north
    S <- bounds$south
    E <- bounds$east
    W <- bounds$west
    BB = matrix(c(W, E, E, W, W, N, N, S, S, N), nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
    BB = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(
      BB
    )), 1)))
    as.vector(countries[which(gIntersects(countries, BB, byid = TRUE)),]$NAME)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example for option 2

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)


ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap") ,
                verbatimTextOutput('myCountries'))

countries <- readShapeSpatial("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

if (!exists('displayed')){
  displayed <<- c("United Kingdom")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  observe({   
    current.coutries <- pointsInBounds()
    new.countries    <- current.coutries[ ! (current.coutries %in% displayed) ]
    # DOWNLOAD new.countries
    displayed <<- unique(c(displayed, pointsInBounds()))   
  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(countries) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -0.1294984,
              lat = 51.4992921,
              zoom = 10)
  })

  output$myCountries <- renderPrint({
    pointsInBounds()

    displayed 
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_bounds, {})
  pointsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$mymap_bounds)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    bounds <- input$mymap_bounds
    N <- bounds$north
    S <- bounds$south
    E <- bounds$east
    W <- bounds$west
    BB = matrix(c(W, E, E, W, W, N, N, S, S, N), nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
    BB = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(
      BB
    )), 1)))
    as.vector(countries[which(gIntersects(countries, BB, byid = TRUE)),]$NAME)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: perfect, you read my thoughts - indeed i wanted to store it between sessions so other users avoided downloading the file and reading into a df. Where should the function to download files go? into this piece? observe({
    displayed <<- unique(c(displayed, pointsInBounds())) 
  })